# Windows 10 upgrade, 32-bit programs, and Windows.old

Tags: windows, windows-10, upgrade, windows.old

I've recently upgraded my system from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  Although some of the UI changes greatly annoy me, I'm leaning towards keeping it at the moment.

However one thing that worries me a bit is the contents of the Windows.old folder that was created during the upgrade.  *Mostly* it seems to contain duplicate folder structures without actual files, or duplicate copies of Microsoft-specific files that have presumably been superseded in Windows 10.  In particular the `C:\Windows.old\Program Files` folder only contains Microsoft apps which also appear in `C:\Program Files`.  Similarly `C:\Windows.old\Users` mostly contains empty folders and copies of the registry, but not anything significant as far as I can tell.

**But** what worries me is that the `C:\Windows.old\Program Files (x86)` folder contains a large number of non-Microsoft apps which do **NOT** appear in my `C:\Program Files (x86)` folder (which conversely only contains Microsoft apps).

(`C:\Program Files (x86)` is 0.7 GB; `C:\Windows.old\Program Files (x86)` is 15.2 GB, so the difference is significant.)

Am I correct in assuming that 10 days after the upgrade, Windows is just going to delete all of these apps?  Can I move them back to the "real" folder before this or do I need to do something else to rescue them?

Comment: Is there any other reason you think this is not accurate? Did you find an application not functioning as it should? Why is it Windows can’t just upgrade and take care of itself without your intervention?

Comment: FYI, there are apps that will make win10 look like win7

Comment: The Windows.old folder is used in case you want to revert back to Windows 7, after upgrading to Windows 10. I don't know the intricacies of how the Windows.old folder is made or used, but you are correct about the deletion. **It will be automatically deleted in 30 days.**

Comment: @DrZoo The Recovery control panel specifically states that returning to Windows 7 is only available for **10 days** after the upgrade.  And I know that's what it's for, I'm just worried about the fact that it contains 90% of my apps (which don't run right now BTW because their shortcuts still point at their original locations outside of Windows.old).

Comment: I didn't know that the upgrade revert is only available for 10 days, but the Windows.old folder will be deleted in 30 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** move applications from `C:\Windows.old\Program Files (x86)` to `C:Program Files (x86)`. This works well for those programs that need no installation, such as Nirsoft's [File Types Manager](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html). Bring over `C:\Windows.old\Program Files (x86)\Common Files` first. Also check `C:\Windows.old\Users` and `C:\Windows.old\ProgramData` for data files that might be needed (e.g. browser profile).

For other applications that set Registry or PATH entries, that add storage locations or that make other changes during installation, just moving the application may not be sufficient. If, after moving over that folder, the application no longer works as expected, full installation is needed.

Windows should *not* delete the files in `C:\Windows.old\Program Files (x86)` until you perform disk cleanup, and it may lock those files to prevent removal *until* a set time has passed. (That may have been 30 days, but now seems to be sooner.)

My own preference is to copy one application's folder at a time and to test if it works properly. My experience is that about half do not require full reinstallation. Disk cleanup is postponed until all needed applications are installed and then waiting a few weeks more.

Comment: This wasn't a clean install, so it did preserve all the registry entries etc required by the applications, it just left the files in the wrong place.  I've moved a few big apps (eg. Visual Studio) back to their original location outside of Windows.old and thus far they all seem to be behaving.  I've made a backup of the rest just in case.

Comment: Glad it worked! BTW, keep product keys in case you find reinstallation *is* needed later. Nirsoft's ProduKey can find some if the original is lost.